# If developer CV is created the text should be edit CV

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

On the Profile page there is a button "Create a Developer CV". If i had created one, the text is not changed. I think it will be better to Name it as "Edit CV" or something like that:

[image]

In the top profile bar, the name of the link to same page is changed to "Edit CV"

[image]

Comment: How long ago did you create your CV? I see a "Link to my Developer CV Here" in that location on my profile. I also see "Edit CV" on the top, next to "Edit Profile".

Comment: I created my cv last week

Comment: Yes on the top there is the link. But in my opinion it should also renamed in the profie view

Comment: I think perhaps your CV and profile aren't linked properly (as I said, I don't see what you see on my profile / cv)? I'm sure I've seen other meta questions with similar things. Don't know what to suggest. If you click the button does it just take you to your current CV?

Comment: Yes it linked to the edit cv page

Comment: It might be cache related? Did you try using a different browser or cleaning the cache?

Comment: It is no cache issue